# Determining Maximum fiber cable speed?

Tags: fiber

Excuse my ignorance here. I have tried googling this 100 ways and can't seem to find the correct wording to get the result I am looking for.

We have some fiber cabling that shows a MFG Date of 02-Mar-00. We are thinking about upgrading our LAN from 10/100 to xGB. Want to know whether we need to replace fiber cabling as well? So, my question is, how do you determine max speed of cable?

Below is the wording printed on the cable

DX12-065D-W Series
62.5/125UM
Ultra-Fox Riser
Type OFNR (UL)
Indoor/Outdoor
02-MAR-00

Comment: The length of a fiber optic cable is a serious limit on its effective speed.  Every meter of ordinary slight imperfections drops the maximum speed it can carry.  Please Edit to include the length of the cable you have, and the length of the distance you need to cover.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Distance and speed are heavily dependent on the type of the cable and the transmission.

The following table is taken from the article
[Fiber Type Vs. Speed and Distance](https://www.lanshack.com/Fiber-Type-vs-Speed-and-Distance.aspx):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

62.5 micron multimode cable (orange colored) I think.
So called OM1 cable. See [here](http://www.fiber-optic-solutions.com/comparison-om1-om2-om3-om4.html) for a extensive overview of the different fiber cable types and specs.

Typically good for 275 meter or 550 meter on 1 Gb/s depending on transceiver type.
For 10 Gb/s range is limited to 33 meters and requires some very hard to find special transceivers.